# Safety of uploadFile in ShinyApp

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

There is a way to take files from user via Shiny app using `inputFile`. I would like to take pdf files from user.  How could i make it secure ? I mean that user will not have possibility to upload 200+ gigabyte file or virus etc. Other possibly concerns or your own experience would be very helpful,like where to store those files, how collect them and so on

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about sanitizing your inputs than it is about shiny. However, it is still valid and an important aspect to consider whenever you allow file uploads in your application.

One way would be to only allow PDFs, but `inputFile` doesn't really support limiting which files to upload (yet). However, you can restrict the size of your file uploads by placing this at the top of your `app.R`-file: `options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)`. This equates to 30 MB, as demonstrated in this [vignette](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html).

This is obviously not the ideal solution. One alternative might be to use a HTML method for uploading files, and then handling those passing those files along to Shiny with some Javascript.